# Javascript simulating classes

Tags: javascript, class

I'm trying to simulate a class in javascript. I'm new to it (and also to stackoverflow)

and want to learn. Somebody who gives me java explained it like this, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
function rectangle (width,height,x,y,jumping)
{
    return { x: x,
             y: y,
             width: width,
             height: height,
             jumping: jumping};
}

var ava = new rectangle (5,5,10,20,10);

alert (x.ava)   ;
```

Help appreciated
Thanks in advance (I hope I post this right)

edit: Thank you Philipp :)

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Is there something interesting in the Javascript error console of your browser?

Comment: Please take the time to read through the help pages about how and what kinds of questions to ask. A minimal understanding of the problem is expected. Removing Clojure tag. This is not Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
// this is how you write a class
function Rectangle(width, hight, x, y, jumping) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = x;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.jumping = jumping;
}

var ava = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 20, 10);
alert(ava.x);
```

also your variable is `ava` and calls `x` you had it backwards `x.ava`.

Comment: what's the difference of using this.x = x instead of x: x ?

Comment: I didn't think that this was the way to write an object/class

Comment: Can I ask you how you add a setter for x to that class, just for an example?

Answer (score 0):

well your variable is not "x"

```
var ava = new rectangle (5,5,10,20,10);
alert (x.ava);  You are looking for a variable x with a property of ava
```

When you run your code you get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

You want to use your variable that has the properties. You should have written it as:

```
alert (ava.x);
```

Comment: what do you mean by that ? I want the x-coordinate from ava. What should I type than?

Comment: @user2815780 read the answer carefully. He already answered that.

Comment: You Sir saved me ALOT of TIME :) Thanks ;)